# How to install Elastic Search and configure on Magento 2.2.X?

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, magento2.2.3, elasticsearch

I want to install Elastic Search on Magento 2.2.X Community Edition. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Server is debian  or centOS??

Comment: Which extension you have used for bridge?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/_installation.html

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala It's centOS.

Comment: You will need an integration with any bridge extension along with ES installation. You can use https://marketplace.magento.com/folio3ecommerce-magento2-module-bingo.html to integrate with Magento 2.2.x Ref: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/214535/56221

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow below steps to install elastic search

1) Trust the Elastic signing key:

```
sudo rpm --import https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
```

2) Create a yum repository configuration to use the Elastic yum repository:

```
[elasticsearch-6.x] name=Elastic repository for 6.x packages baseurl=https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/yum gpgcheck=1 gpgkey=https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch enabled=1 autorefresh=1 type=rpm-md
```

3) Install the official Elastic APT package signing key:

```
wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
```

4) Install the elasticsearch package:

```
sudo yum install -y elasticsearch
```

5) Enable and start the elasticsearch service:

```
sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
```

6) To determine whether or not the service has started successfully, view the most recent logs:

```
 systemctl status elasticsearch
```

**Example Of 2nd Step**

> Create a file with a .repo extension (for example, elastic.repo) in your /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory and add the following lines:

```
[elastic-6.x]
name=Elastic repository for 6.x packages
baseurl=https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/yum
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
enabled=1
autorefresh=1
type=rpm-md
```

Comment: We'll check that and let you know.

Comment: Can you please give an example of the second step?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. please check updated answer

Comment: You are always welcome @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. :)

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala, can you help me with this ? I'm sure you've answer for it.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255300/magento-2-3-how-to-use-elastic-search

Comment: @WebDeveloper I have not setup elastic search in 2.3.0 yet so I can not answer 100%

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala, Cool No Worries. I've manged to install Smile Elastic but troubling for configuring default Elastic search.