# Magento 2.3 : How to use Elastic search?

Tags: magento2.3, elasticsearch

As we all know that since Magento 2.3 CE released It supports Elastic Search without using any 3rd party vendor.

How Can I configure it ?

**Note : I don't want to use other vendors for now.**

Comment: You can refer the official doc https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html

Comment: is Magento 2.3 CE the community edition (open source) or the enterprise edition?

Comment: Community Edition